# Python ThreadPoolExecutor is not waiting long enough for task completion

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Basically, I need to process (convert form PDF, resize and save) multiple images, and then load them into `tkinter`. Here's the relevant part of the code.

```
def part(i):
    global prog
    zoom = 5    # zoom factor
    mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)
    page = doc.loadPage(i) #number of page
    pix = page.getPixmap(matrix = mat)
    output = "Output_Images\\Ques_"+str(i+1)+".png"
    pix.writePNG(output)
    prog += ((1/pages)*50)
    progress['value'] = prog
    load.update_idletasks()

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 4)
for i in range(0, pages):
    executor.submit(part, i)

launch_main()
```

The `launch_main()` function puts all the images, with a couple of more widgets into a `tk.Text` within a loop. The problem I am facing is that, there are times when a couple of images at the last (variable in every run) are not getting inserted into the `tk.Text`.

The `Output_Images` directory has all the images, which implies that the `launch_main()` function is being called earlier than expected, and hence it's loop ends before the all the images are saved.

But if I do this instead, i.e., add `time.sleep()`, it seems to work fine.

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 4)
for i in range(0, pages):
    executor.submit(part, i)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Is there any better solution to this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Call "shutdown" on the executor.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I was unaware about this, it's all good now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would utilize the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with the `with` clause in order to avoid any unexpected behavior.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for i in range(0, pages):
        executor.submit(part, i)

print("All tasks completed")
launch_main()
```

Comment: Undersood. Thanks a lot for the quick reply.